Error in libcrypto when attempting to create Public/Private Keys in PEM format with Passphrase in FIPS mode
After attempting to create a public/private key using the following commands with a passphrase I receive this error
Saving key "/home/.ssh/rsa_id" failed: error in libcrypto

If I run this command without entering either the passphrase or the PEM option it works but I need both not one or the other. The issue appears to be with using a passphrase together with the PEM option which I need for our Nessus scans to get proper credentials because of this type of error "Failed to parse ssh keys".
Commands:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f

Output:
Generating pubic/private rsa key pair. Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):

I enter a passphrase here
Enter same passphrase again:

I enter the passphrase again
Saving key "(file path and name)" failed: error in libcrypto

I've been able to create credentials without the PEM option and the passphrase but never with both. I've tried to convert the file to PEM format and add a passphrase but I always receive the erro in libcrypto.

Have you tried omitting the -f- at the end of your command?  The -foption needs an argument, but if you omit it from the command, thessh-keygen` will default to a path+file name that's similar to the one you seem to want (judging by the error message).

Also, please edit your question to include the Linux distro you're using, and any relevant version number (e.g., Ubuntu 22.04, Debian 12)

You can't do that in FIPS mode. What OpenSSH (ssh-keygen) calls PEM format is really the traditional aka legacy format defined by OpenSSL (previously SSLeay) which uses a password-based encryption scheme that depends on MD5. FIPS 140 prohibits MD5, except a few special cases not applicable here. Either you change your requirements or you must use non-FIPS mode at least temporarily, possibly on a different or virtual system
